# Android Talkback not announcing tab count inside a tablist

Tags: android, ionic-framework, accessibility, talkback

Currently using Ionic 4 and there is no count being announced for tabs (e.g. Tab 1 of 3). On iOS this works perfectly fine, just on Android its not working.

Here is some example code:

```
<ul role="tablist">
  <li 
  role="tab" 
  *ngFor="let tab of tabs; index as i"
  [attr.aria-selected]="currentIndex === i"
  [attr.aria-controls]="tab.id"
  [attr.aria-label]="isNative ? tab.title : ''"
  >
  {{tab.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Not sure what else I am missing? I was also thinking on create a specific aria label just for Android but prefer a more native solution

Comment: Try running the [TABS example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/examples/tabs-manual/) from the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) from your Android device to see if it has the same problem. The example sounds ok on iOS. I don't have an Android to try it on. If Android doesn't announce it, then it sounds like an Android limitation and not a problem with your code.